# Use external file js in robot-framework

Tags: javascript, automation, automated-tests, robotframework

I have a file js in my project

```java
export function myFunction(parametro) {
  return "This is result  " + param;
}
```

and my file .robot

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Carregar Funções JavaScript
    Open Browser    https://google.com    Firefox
    Execute JavaScript    var script = document.createElement('script');
    ...    script.src = '/external-libs/robot-shared-function/index.js';
    ...    document.head.appendChild(script);

Usar Função JavaScript
    ${resultado}=    Execute JavaScript    return minhaFuncaoGlobal('algumParâmetro');
    Log    ${resultado}
```

But in results I have :

```bash
Usar Função JavaScript                                                | FAIL |
JavascriptException: Message: ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Teste-Lib                                                             | FAIL |
2 tests, 1 passed, 1 failed
```

I would like  know how to  use external function of file js

Answer (score 0):

Not possible like that, browser's security feature's will block loading external files that way.

What you need to do is to convert that file into loadable module and inject it via `Execute Javascript`.

Comment: How  I can what do ?

Comment: Either you modify your js project to be a module that browser supports or make the transform with webpack or babel or similar tool. Load the file and run the context w/ Execute Javascript.    If you need example; https://github.com/marketSquare/robotframework-seleniumtestability  does this.   Building happens via "build" command thats in package.json  file and then injection  is in plugin.py's _inject_testability() method.

Comment: This example url return 404 not found do you have other ?